# Trying to remove duplicates words in a String using sed of MacOS

Tags: macos, sed, bsd

I'm trying to remove duplicates words in a string using sed from MacOS using the following command:

```
sed -r 's/^([A-Za-z0-9_]+) \1$/\1/' <<< 'The best of of The United Kingdom'
```

But it only returns

```
The best of of United Kingdom
```

What I'm missing? Could you guys give me hand? Please.

Comment: It is not quite possible to do that without word boundaries. Try `sed -E 's/[[:<:]]([[:alnum:]_]+)([[:space:]]+\1)+[[:>:]]/\1/'`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/g8FmQb) (changed for GNU sed compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\([^ ]* \)\1\+/\1/' input_file
The best of The United Kingdom
```

Your original code had unneeded anchors `^|$`. Here is a fixed version

```
$ sed -r 's/([A-Za-z0-9_]* )\1+/\1/' <<< 'The best of of The United Kingdom'
The best of The United Kingdom
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But for some reason, it's not working in my machine. I tried your two suggestions but it's still returning duplicated words. Btw I'm using MacOS Monterey.

Answer (score 1):

I installed gnu-sed.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are unnecesarily anchoring the regex at the start and end of line. Remove `^` and `$`. Change `-r` to the POSIX `-E` and it will work on BSD/Mac sed. You also need the `g` flag to replace multiple repeating word patterns.

```
sed -E 's/([A-Za-z0-9_]+) \1/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sed -E 's/[[:<:]]([[:alnum:]_]+)([[:space:]]+\1)+[[:>:]]/\1/'
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [[:<:]]                  the boundary between a non-word char or
                           start of string and a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [[:alnum:]_]+            any character of: letters and digits,
                             '_' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [[:space:]]+             any character of: whitespace characters
                             (like \s) (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [[:>:]]                  the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Comment: [[:<:]]  and   [[:>:]]
Interesting... I didn't know that